# How does the Flatten() Layer work in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Im currently working with tensorflow and neural networks and im quite new to the topic.

Im having a stack of 4 images passed to my conv network in the shape of (4,160,120,1) as the images are in grayscale.

After passing my images through the neural network i wanted to flatten the images into one long array that gets passed to dense layers.

But after using Flatten() on the output of my neural network i get a 2 dimensional array in the shape of (4, 2240) instead of a long one dimensional array.

Why is that and what would i need to do to flatten it to a 1D array? Just use Flatten() again?

Im asking because my goal is to concatenate the flattened with another input which is one dimensional but i get an array that concatenate wont work bc they dont have the same shape

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have a stack of 4 images, 160x120x1 and you want to flatten them into one 1D array? You will lose most if not all of the spatial relationship between the 4 images.

Comment: Okay. But i need to concatenate another array to the output of my convolutional layer. 
Would i need to transform my (10,) array into an (4,10) array to add this additional input?

Comment: What is your goal? My guess is that since you are stacking images, you are interested in the spatial relationship between them. if you are, a 3D conv network might me more useful to you. 

If you are concatenating the other input and don't want to lose that information, you will have to stack the other input in 4s as well, with those same images in that order.

Comment: My goal is to implement reinforcement learning for a robot to navigate through an environment with using the depth gray scale images of the environment. The input is a 4 image stack and after passing the images through a conv network i wanted to concatenate information about the goal. Like distance and angle to the goal.

And then pass that concatenated information to dense layers and then output my Q values

Comment: Then you’d want to pass the correct distance and angle to each stack of the images, you would have to concatenation the flattened tensor with a (4,10) tensor. I’m unsure if flattening it later will help or not, because a dense layer after flattening the 4 stack image will most likely not give you any additional information about the surroundings. I would suggest doing each image separately in the network, then passing then concatenate the information to make a 1D feature array for each image. Then using this in a ML system such as LightGBM to try and get more information.

Answer (score 1):

Keras layers don't affect batch dimension. You have to use `tf.reshape()` before feeding your data to the model:

```
input1 = tf.reshape(input1, (-1,))
output = model(input1, input2) # exclude Flatten layer from your model
```

Comment: So I would need to reshape after i flattened it to the (4,2240) and before concatenating the the other array?

Comment: @Ronnee you have to reshape before feeding to NN - please see edits